# What's the meaning of the term "out of touch intellectuals"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was reading the following sentence in Wikipedia and I couldn't realize the meaning of the mentioned term:

"In Canadian politics, latte drinking is used to portray **people as out of touch intellectuals** and the antithesis of the Tim Hortons coffee drinker that's considered representative of an ordinary Canadian"

Comment: Definition 2 here: [out of touch](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+touch) *- Unable to appreciate or understand the concerns or difficulties of others.*

Comment: Personally I would have hyphenated it as "out-of-touch intellectuals" to make it clear that the "out of touch" being used as an adjectival phrase modifying "intellectuals" rather than letting you think it goes with "people" at first and having to readjust when you get to the word "intellectuals".

Comment: @Hellion I think it can be read either way, and the difference is not very significant. If someone is an out-of-touch intellectual, then "out of touch" applies to them as well.

Comment: Echoes here of the "cowardly Eastern liberal establishment" in the parody writing in "Good As Gold" by Joseph Heller, ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Heller#Novels

Answer (score 1):

The word *intellectual*, meaning a person who tends to be cerebral in his or her outlook, preferring to discuss theoretical things rather than practical things, can be a compliment *or* an insult.

If the word is meant as an insult, the person who is using the word looks for behaviors in intellectuals that "prove" they deserve to be insulted.

If a person calls another person *cheap*, for example, he might call attention to the habit of that person never to pick up the tab when dining with friends at a restaurant. That behavior of never paying for a meal would be an indication of the person's cheapness. People might even begin saying of this person, "Oh, there's fast Donald," meaning ironically that he's very slow at paying for a meal among friends.

Likewise, the drinking of latte, while perfectly innocent under normal circumstances, can be used as "proof" that a person is not only an intellectual but that he engages in behavior--in this case the drinking of latte--which is typical of intellectuals. For that reason, then, the latte-drinking has a negative connotation.

Another way of insulting intellectuals is by simply calling them "latte-drinking, out-of-touch intellectuals and snobs." The antonym of a latte-drinking snob, then, would be "a coffee-drinking realist," who is by nature, supposedly, more practical, more inclusive, and more down to earth and humble.